# i want to send the result through res.send() through eval function

Tags: express

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
app.get('/',req, res) => {
res.send('eval(`let x=10 
x+2`)')
```

})
** I want 12 is sended as a result through eval function**

Comment: Why should you send it with eval?

Comment: is it possible or not ??